# Render list value updated by react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

There is a counter application which should render the as the countdown happens.

The *first render* should be 10

The *second render* should be 10 9

The *third render* should be 10 9 8

and so on ...

Using react hooks, accomplishing this task is being a challenge as the component is not being re-rendered when the value is updated for the variable storing the countdown value.

A timer is used to update the value of countdown after every 1.5 seconds. In the `console.log` statement that the value for the variable is updated but the re-render of the component doesn't occur.

```js
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const ListCounter = props => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState([10]);
  const [timerId, setTimerId] = useState(null);
  const countRef = useRef(count);
  countRef.current = count;
  const timerIdRef = useRef(timerId);
  timerIdRef.current = timerId;

  function calculate() {
    initialize();
  }

  const initialize = () => {
    setTimerId(
      setInterval(() => {
        let temp = countRef.current;
        if (temp[temp.length - 1] === 6) {
          clearInterval(timerIdRef.current);
          console.log("STOP!");
        } else {
          setCount(count => {
            temp.push(temp[temp.length - 1] - 1);
            console.log("TEMP: ", temp);
            return temp;
          });
        }
      }, 1500)
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Grid container justify="center">
        <Grid item>
          {count.map((v1, i) => {
            return (
              <Typography key={i} variant="h1" component="h2" gutterBottom>
                {v1},
              </Typography>
            );
          })}

          <Button variant="contained" onClick={calculate}>
            Count down
          </Button>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ListCounter;
```

Please find the CodeSandbox link for the complete code

Any suggestions are welcomed.

[image: Edit nifty-frost-6hev3]

Comment: Please edit the necessary code to reproduce the problem *into the question itself*. If that would make the code section too long, then please *create a minimal reproduction case that demonstrates the problem*. It is also not at all clear why you're using `useRef`.

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks for your suggestion. The question is updated with the complete code.

Comment: You're mutating state which is unsupported in React. I also still don't understand why you need `useRef` or what you are trying to accomplish with it. This seems overly elaborate for a countdown timer. But yeah, you need to clone your array rather than mutating the original.

Comment: Since I am using `setInterval` I am unable to reference the initial value of the countdown list, hence I am using `useRef` to get the current value of the variable.

Ref: https://upmostly.com/tutorials/settimeout-in-react-components-using-hooks

I want to show the previous and the current value of the timer on the UI before stopping it. Hence I am using list to save all the vaues.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the problem that `useRef` is solving in that tutorial. You don't need it here. You just (again) need to not mutate your array but to copy it instead.

Comment: Oh! I tried without using `useRef` and I was only able to get the initial value of the array whenever the setInterval function was called.

Leaving that aside, can you please suggest me the code which I should modify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @JaredSmith for pointing me in the correct direction.

```js
const initialize = () => {
    setTimerId(
      setInterval(() => {
        let temp = countRef.current.slice(); // <---------
        if (temp[temp.length - 1] === 6) {
          clearInterval(timerIdRef.current);
          console.log("STOP!");
        } else {
          setCount(count => {
            temp.push(temp[temp.length - 1] - 1);
            console.log("TEMP: ", temp);
            return temp;
          });
        }
      }, 1500)
    );
  };
```